# PrimeNG datatable setting rowStyleClass is setting the highlighted style

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I'm using the rowStyleClass and a datatable like all the examples I've seen where, in the html, I have:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="group.data" sortField="displayName" sortMode="single" [rowStyleClass]="getSelected" 
        [rowTrackBy]="dataTrackBy" [responsive]="true">
```

and with a method:

```
getSelected(rowData: DataItem) {
    return rowData.selected ? 'selected-bg' : 'unselected-bg';
}
```

and css:

```
.unselected-bg {
    background-color: white
}

.selected-bg {
    background-color: #d9edf7;
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when I set the rowData.selected to true, the highlighted state gets set, as seen in this element copy:

```
<tr class="ui-datatable-odd ui-widget-content selected-bg ui-datatable-even ui-state-highlight" ng-reflect-klass="ui-widget-content selected-bg" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
```

From there, the row turns the highlight color and setting the selected value back to false does not remove it. What am I doing wrong? I've also thought of using the rowStyleMap property, but I didn't really understand the documentation on how to use.

I'm using PrimeNG v. 4.1.2

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem. How do you select or unselect a row ? Could you eventually create a Plunker ?

Answer (score 1):

Proper way is using the new p-table and ngClass, here is a demo;

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/style

Comment: so building a p-datatable from a p-table?